# Installing NumPy using Pip on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, ssl, pip

I downloaded Python 3.6.1 and it came with Pip preinstalled. I wrote this command to install numpy

```
C:\Python36-32>python -m pip install numpy
```

To which I got this as the output:

> Collecting numpy   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming
>   the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:749) - skipping   Could not find a version that
>   satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: ) No matching
>   distribution found for numpy

How do I solve this?
PS: I did this on Windows 10, Command Prompt running as administrator.

Comment: `pip install numpy` is the command i run

Comment: I am getting the same result for that command, too.

Comment: If it was me i would not use the most recent version of python. If possible stick to 3.5/3.4 it's the same syntax but more compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using the following command:

```
pip install numpy --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751768/7529378) answer helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using the below Command:

```
python.exe -m pip install numpy
```

For ex:

```
C:\Users\Suresh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37>python.exe -m pip install numpy
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you first add python  path to your computer by checking the box with add path on your python exe.Then run `pip install numpy` on your command prompt.

Comment: the answer is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Dockerfile or Linux), we wanted to get pip modules installed from requirement*.txt files, which had **locked-in** module's versions defined in the file **and** fetched from an **internal Artifactory** server (**rather than** going to online i.e. *pypi.org*)

Ex: requirements.txt file(s)

```
numpy==1.16.2
pandas==1.0.3
..
...
```

To fix the issue: I had to use `NO_PROXY=<value>` available as an environment variable.

Let's say, if you artifactory server is: my-artifactory.**company.local** or my-artifactory.**company.com**, then all we need to ensure is that `NO_PROXY` variable has that hostname's "**domain**" part listed in its value.

i.e. for
my-artifactory.**company.com** or my-artifactory.**company.local**, value inside

NO_PROXY variable must have: `,.company.com,.company.local,...` in it.

**Sample** exported variable (**at command line $ prompt**):

`export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,169.254.169.254,169.254.169.123,.somecompany.com,.company.com,.company.local,pki.company.com,s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com,s3-fips-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com,rds.amazonaws.com,10.201.12.244,10.201.44.62,10.201.32.261`

====

If you are using a `Dockerfile`, then, ensure you have ARG/ENV variable are set correctly.
ARG is used during build time (can be overridden at command line using --build-arg option sent to `docker build -t tag .` where it'll search current directory for a Dockerfile and create an image. ENV is used at run time (`docker run`) and can be overridden as well.

**Sample Dockerfile** is:

```
FROM python:3.7

MAINTAINER giga.sangal@company.com

ARG PYTHONBUFFERED=0
ARG HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.ext.company.com:80
ARG HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.ext.company.com:80
ARG NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,169.254.169.254,.company.com,.company.local,pki.company.com,s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com,s3-fips-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com,rds.amazonaws.com

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=${PYTHONBUFFERED}
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=${HTTPS_PROXY}
ENV HTTP_PROXY=${HTTP_PROXY}
ENV NO_PROXY=${NO_PROXY}

# If there are 3 requirements files in source control, I'm copy all for pip install, you don't have to. Use what modules you want / file you want.    
RUN mkdir -p code
COPY requirements.txt /code
COPY requirements-test.txt /code
COPY requirements-dev.txt /code

WORKDIR /code

# You can fetch from pypi.org but in my case, this was a security issue.
# RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --trusted-host my-artifactory.company.local -r requirements.txt -r requirements-test.txt -r requirements-dev.txt --index-url http://my-artifactory.company.local:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local-deps/simple --disable-pip-version-check
```

The main line, which solved the issue in my case, was using the NO_PROXY (as listed above).

Any issues related to pip module not found, or module version not found, or any SSL errors  `SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError` like errors, went away after applying the above NO_PROXY at **cmd line** or in **Dockerfile**:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/requests/
```

or

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests
```

or

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.16.2
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.16.2
```